# ¿Cómo se dice "kid's meal" en español?

Tags: vocabulario, comida

I'm pretty new to Spanish, but I'm learning with Coffee Break Spanish/listening to TV/Radio/learning vocab via word of the day...pretty much anything I can get my hands on.

Anyway, if I'm ordering a meal at a fast food restaurant and I want to use the phrase 'kid's meal' (or something similar), what words would I use? For example would a 'kid's sandwich' be 'un sandwich de niño'? Or 'un sandwich de los niños?'. How do you use it in a sentance? 'Quisiera ...'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, `kid's meal` is translated as `menú infantil`.

@c.p. answers are ok. In Spain, you should always say `sándwich`, because `emparedado` sounds a bit old-fashioned.

Comment: Be aware that, in Spain, *sándwich* always implies sliced bread. If you use French bread, the right word would be *bocadillo*.

Comment: @Gorpik Totally true!

Answer (score 2):

> Comida para niños.

Entonces en el ejemplo, la expresión correcta es:

> Sándwich para niños.

Otra opción es

> Emparedado/bocadillo para niños.

si quieres evitar el anglicismo.

Comment: So 'Quisiera un emparedado para niños.' would be the best way to be understood?

Comment: No. I was wrong, *sánwich* is perfectly acceptable. But it bears a tilde. See my edit in a minute.

Comment: Emparedado se dice solo en america central. En españa es Bocadillo

Answer (score 2):

Just plain

```
menu infantil
```

which means a customized menu for kids.